# SelectList to filter results based on sql tables bool column for "Retired"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a selectlist which I've setup in a ViewModel and DropDownFor and it already has itself ordered as u can see below but I need it to filter so that the 3rd column "Retired" if it's value is "0" all those results are show but not if it's "1".

I was thinking I would need to add after the .OrderBy(...).Where(m=>m.Retired but don't know how exactly I'd filter it from there and ofc it doesn't have to be done in the VM but that's just how I was able to implement the OrderBy filter.

VM

```
List<Reason> reasonList = _db.Reasons.OrderBy(m=>m.Description).ToList();
        ReasonList = new SelectList(reasonList, "Id", "Description");
```

DDF

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.amwrAudit.AppTherRea, Model.ReasonList, "---------------------- Select a Reason ---------------------")%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

`.Where(m=>!m.Retired)` . Because it is a bool, no equal signs are needed.

If you are uncomfortable with that syntax you can still type `.Where(m=>m.Retired == false)`

Comment: if it's that simple and I was so close to the solution I'm gona shoot myself (joke)

Comment: Yep it unfortunatly it isn't that simple "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'boo' and 'string'" looking anyways to modify it to still work but not holding out hopes.

Comment: turns out you were close and all I had to do was instead of [== 1] or [== "1"] it was [== false] since it is a bool, if you edit your answer to include/display this then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Myzifer Edited the answer to better comply with yout data type :-)