# How do I get my dropdownlist to be in alphabetical order for my project in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the elements of my dropdown displayed in alphabetical order. Following is the code:

```
<select id="participantIds" data-placeholder="Select Participants" class="chosen-select" 
    multiple style="width:100%;" tabindex="4" 
    asp-for="UserIds"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "Id", "Name"))">
```

I've  tried to do it with `OrderBy but it doesn't seem to work for `ViewBag`? How do I do it with JavaScript or Jquery?

My `ViewBag` is of:

```
this.ViewBag.Users = await this._eventSessionService.GetAllUsers(eventSessionId);
```

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just use the OrderBy on whatever code puts the users *into* the viewbag.. Show that code and I'll show you the orderby

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alphabetically Ordering a SelectList in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796211/alphabetically-ordering-a-selectlist-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ViewBag` is dynamic therefore you cannot use the `Orderby` or other methods on a dynamic property

Now assuming that your `ViewBag.Users` is of `List<Users>`, you can cast the property to a known type collection and the extension method should then be available.

```
<select id="participantIds" data-placeholder="Select Participants" class="chosen-select" 
    multiple style="width:100%;" tabindex="4" 
    asp-for="UserIds"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList((ViewBag.Users as List<Users>).OrderBy(x=>x.Name), "Id", "Name"))">
```

An alternative is sorting the list in the controller before assigning it to the `ViewBag`:

```
var userList = await this._eventSessionService.GetAllUsers(eventSessionId);
this.ViewBag.Users = userList.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
```

You can also use `JQuery` to sort our your list after it has been initialized:

```
var myList = $('#participantIds');
var selected = myList.val();
var opts_list = myList.find('option');
opts_list.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
myList.html('').append(opts_list);
myList.val(selected);
```